# How To Persist ip Rule And Route Whenever Server Rebooted?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, iptables, networkmanager

I'm using Centos 7 Server And I Would Like To Save ip Rule And Route Whenever Server Rebooted.

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 128
ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.y/y dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via z.z.z.z
```

The mentioned Rule and Route lose once i reboot the server which means i need to run the 3 commands each time server rebooted.

I need to make ip rule and route persist whenever server is rebooted.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_in_ifcfg_files.html

Comment: [*RHEL7 Networking Guide: Configuring Static Routes in ifcfg files*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-editing_network_configuration_files#sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_in_ifcfg_files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. The file states

> Please note that you must run `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local` to ensure that this script will be executed during boot.

So:

```bash
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Then place your commands above the last line

```bash
touch /var/lock/subsys/local
```

There is better way using relevant configuration files. Rules and routes can be specified using corresponding file names. All the relevant configuration files are given below. (The device names may differ.)

```bash
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1
```

To create a named routing table, use `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. I added `128 mynet`.

```bash
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
128     mynet
```

The EL 7.x `/etc/sysconfig/network` file. The default route is `GATEWAY`.

```ini
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=hostname.sld.tld
GATEWAY=10.10.10.1
```

THE EL 7.x `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file, without `HWADDR` and "UUID". This configures a static IP address for `eth0` without using *NetworkManager*.

```ini
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTOCOL=none
IPADDR=10.10.10.140
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=10.10.10.0
BROADCAST=10.10.10.255
```

THE EL 7.x `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` file, without `HWADDR` and `UUID`. This configures a static IP address for `eth1` without using *NetworkManager*.

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTOCOL=none
IPADDR=192.168.100.140
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.100.0
BROADCAST=192.168.100.255
```

The EL 7.x `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` file. The default route was already specified in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

```bash
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth1 table mynet
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth1 table mynet
```

The EL 7.x `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1` file:

```bash
from 192.168.100.0/24 lookup mynet
```

### Update for RHEL8

This method described above works with RHEL 6 & RHEL 7 as well as the derivatives, but for RHEL 8 and derivatives, one must first install `network-scripts` to use the method described above.

```bash
dnf install network-scripts
```

The installation produces a warning that `network-scripts` will be removed in one of the next major releases of RHEL and that NetworkManager provides `ifup`/`ifdown` scripts as well.

Comment: in case if i gonna use the first option only are it's gonna save ip rule and ip route command even if server rebooted? and if yes, shall i insert the 3 commands as it is?

Comment: It should, yes. `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` is a script that runs whichever commands we put in it.

Comment: RHEL8 part - network-scripts installation, doesn't make it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, but want to complement the accepted answer. It is not strictly necessary to install network-scripts package in RHEL8.

The following files still get picked up by NetworkManager:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1
```

The following files no longer get picked up by NetworkManager

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1
```

However, you can define rules in the ifcfg-eth0 scripts like such:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
ROUTING_RULE_1="from 192.168.100.0/24 table 5"
...
```

To load settings from the files to NetworkManager, execute:

```
$ sudo nmcli connection reload
```

You will then see the routing rules if you run:

```
$ nmcli connection show eth0
$ nmcli connection show eth0 | grep rules
```

To apply NetworkManager configuration to devices and make them active, execute:

```
$ sudo nmcli device reapply eth0
```

Now you should have rules and routie visible with:

```
$ ip route list all
$ ip rule list
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use iproute2, so

```
# ip rule save > /[somepath]/your-ruleset.bin
```

will save your rules.
And next time you should just

```
# ip rule restore < /[somepath]/your-ruleset.bin
```