# Route all HTTP/HTTPS traffic through specific interface using newer kernels ( >= 4.17)

Tags: routing, iproute

My question is very similar to [Output traffic on different interfaces based on destination port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port). However, that question was asked in 2011. Now we have newer kernels that can have ip rules with tcp or udp selectors ("policy routing now has a leg in layer 4"): source - [see comment on this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456898/15010).

I am new to routing, so I only know as much as I have read in the answers on unix.stackexchange.com. I got most of my solution ideas from [Routing port traffic over specific interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581419/routing-port-traffic-over-specific-interface).

I have two interfaces eth1 (10.0.0.182) and eth0 (192.168.1.2). My default route is for eth0. **I want all http and https traffic to route through eth1 instead of the default route.** Everything else can remain unchanged.

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

The device at 10.0.0.1 is a Comcast modem that acts as a DHCP server, firewall, etc. The public IP address is a Comcast IP.

Here are the steps I think I need to do to get this to work using the newer ip rules features.

```
# add a new (secondary) table:
echo "200 comcast-route" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Populate secondary routing table
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table comcast-route

# relax Strict Reverse Path Forwarding to Loose RPF 
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter=2
#NOTE: my system already has this value, so no change is needed
# net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 2

# specify alternate routes when using specific destination ports
# iif lo below means "from local"
ip rule add iif lo ipproto tcp dport 80 lookup 80
ip rule add iif lo ipproto tcp dport 443 lookup 80
```

Does all that look correct? If it does not work, how do I revert those changes?

Finally, when all is working as expected, how do I make it persistent? I see an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365380/how-to-persist-ip-rule-and-route-whenever-server-rebooted), but I assume the suggestion of using  `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` is out dated. Is there a better way to persist these rules?

Comment: `lookup 80` should be changed to `lookup 200` (or `lookup comcast-route` even if I don't understand why everybody absolutely wants to not use a number).

Comment: @A.B Thank you. I'll refrain from using a number and use `lookup comcast-route` as you suggest.

Comment: I suggested the opposite heh: just using numbers. Anyway it doesn't matter as long as it's the correct value.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for clarifying. Sorry I misunderstood. I'll use numbers if that's considered best practice. Either way, thanks for pointing out the error.